# Making one simple face

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

I made this model and for some reason this face is made up of multiple faces is there some way I could merge them into one or get rid of the edges?

Comment: Please provide a .blend file

Comment: Try selecting All in Edit mode and then M > Merge by Distance, but as @retr0 says we'll really need to see your blend file to see exactly what you're talking about. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it

Comment: If you're talking about the initial large face, the diagonal edges are created when you cut holes in it as Blender won't allow a hole in the middle of a face without connecting edges. They won't be visible in rendered view.

Comment: Hello if you do a hole (like a window) you'll always need edges that connect the inner edges with the outer edges it this is what you're talking about

Comment: Oh I figured It out I wanted to remove the lines so it'd be easy to Uv map but I Uv mapped it with them and had no problem. Thanks for the help though!